# dúvida com o sistema grid do bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 1</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 4</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 5</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 6</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 7</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 8</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 9</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 10</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 11</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

o correto não em cada `row` deve-se ter um total de 12 de colunas?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><p>Box 1</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><p>Box 4</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

segui este exemplo:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=grid-layout-for-all-devices

Comment: Meu caro, você já respondeu a pergunta, qual seria sua duvida ?

Comment: o primeiro exemplo é correto?

Comment: Não, porque você divide a linha em 12 espaço, existe um site que você baixa as grids para desenhar em cima assim as coisas ficam mais claras.
http://960.gs/ assim você consegue baixar, caso tenha duvida é so chamar.

Answer (score 2):

O correto é cada row ter uma grid, que a soma de suas colunas seja igual a 12.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Coluna 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Coluna 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Coluna 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Coluna 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Coluna 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para informações mais detalhadas, acesse: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: peguei de um site de tutoriais, o primeiro exemplo. eles estão ensinando errado então? rsrs

Comment: Sim! Não é correto adicionar várias classes de coluna na mesma div. Além disso, o col-sm, col-md, col-lg e o col-xs são pra finalidades diferentes. Segue o link do Bootstrap, para que você entenda melhor: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options